# ruby on rails tutorial:stuck on listing all articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby on rails tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-articles

I'm following the directions, but the template is not rendering;

I did try copy and pasting multiple times.
please help; I'm sure it's a small configuration thing.  everything up until now in the tutorial works fine.
(can show an individual article, and create one)

ps: using ruby 2.3:

```
Jills-MacBook-Pro:blog jsinger$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

the html looks like:

```
Listing articles

<% @articles.each do |article| %> <% end %>
Title   Text
<%= article.title %>    <%= article.text %>
```

(I have two articles saved)

```
my code is: index.html: (in app/views/articles)

<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

controller: (blog/app/controllers/application_controller.rb)

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id]);
  end

  def home
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create

    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title,:text)
    end
end
```

Comment: the home tag was my try to use another route...it didn't work; the code stated that an article with id=home not found

Comment: shouldn't it be `index.html.erb` ?

Comment: How about a much more usable title for your question?

Comment: @theTinMan done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename index.html to index.html.erb so the embedded ruby can be interpreted.

Comment: thank you! huge help.  kept reading over the tutorials and not catching that detail